# How can I create new columns with the values of multiple old columns?

Tags: r, data-science

first time posting so if something is wrong please let me know, I have a dataframe in R that is divided in the following way:

| location | type | amount | produt |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| a | x | 10 | p1 |
| a | x | 20 | p2 |
| b | x | 50 | p5 |
| b | y | 100 | p10 |

In the end I need to group the locations into a single line and make the "type" column to become new columns with the value of the "product" and "amount" column, just like this :

| location | A_P_X | A_P_Y |
| --- | --- | --- |
| a | p1_10,p2_20 |  |
| b | p5_50 | p10_100 |

I tried to make the new coluns using one hot encoding but I run into problem when tring to fill the new columns based on their original "type" value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
library(tidyverse)
df %>%
  unite("val", produt:amount, sep = "_") %>%
  mutate(type = paste0("A_P_", toupper(type))) %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = type, values_from = val, 
              values_fn = list(val = ~paste(., collapse = ", ")))
```

result

```
# A tibble: 2 x 3
  location A_P_X        A_P_Y  
  <chr>    <chr>        <chr>  
1 a        p1_10, p2_20 NA     
2 b        p5_50        p10_100
```

Comment: Thank you for th help! it worked perfectly here as well